# Update a column to a BIT value based on the result of an is null query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that will set a bit value, based on whether another column is null or not.

For example:

```
UPDATE @tmpRank
SET IsXYSale = NOT dbo.Sales_XForY.ID IS NULL
FROM @tmpRank
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sales_XForY ON SaleId = @tmpRank.SaleId
```

I'm getting a syntax error on the NOT keyword, but I can't see how to correct the query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SET IsXYSale = CASE WHEN dbo.Sales_XForY.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE @tmpRank
SET IsXYSale = CASE WHEN dbo.Sales_XForY.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM @tmpRank
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sales_XForY ON SaleId = @tmpRank.SaleId
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has no implied boolean

```
UPDATE @tmpRank
SET IsXYSale = CASE WHEN dbo.Sales_XForY.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM @tmpRank
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sales_XForY ON SaleId = @tmpRank.SaleId
```

In this case, you can leverage how bit works: any non-zero, non-null values becomes 1. It assumes that you can never have 0 as an ID value of course...

```
SET IsXYSale = ISNULL(dbo.Sales_XForY.ID, 0)
```

Comment: @OlegDok: good point. Everyine does IDENTITY (1,1) though and MySQL wouldn't allow 0 so *probably* would be OK

Comment: yep, but you surely know - if something can happen - it happens, especially in DB 8-)